# ngx translate angular, how to pass html formatted text to placeholder attribute

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have the following problem. 
My translation key looks like this:

```
{
  "key": 'Lorem <strong>inpsum</strong>'
}
```

and some part of html code:

```
<form>
  <input [placeholder]="'key | translate'">
</form>
```

Now, how can I pass a key to placeholder if I want to have html formatting?. Currently in my input I can see the text: Lorem < strong > ipsum < /strong >.

Comment: Let's put ngx-translate aside. How would you add a formatted placeholder in a plain html?

Comment: Using css for example. But here I would like to add format to some part of string

Comment: But we are talking about HTML tags. How can you provide HTML tags into your placeholder that they won't be visible as plain text? Could you share a piece of such code so I could reproduce it?

Comment: In Angular you can use [innerHTML] https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-translated-placeholder

Comment: I know, but this won't help you with a placeholder. I just want to say that there is no way to add markupped placeholder even in plain HTML. So it won't be possible in Angular either. Unless you create some custom input components.

Answer (score 11):

It's just as simple as `InnerHTML`. For example:

```
<input placeholder="{{'key' | translate}}">
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to translate it in your .ts file with **instant** function of translate service and save it in a variable. Then you should access it from this variable.

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

[...]

constructor(
  private readonly translateService: TranslateService,
) { }

keyTranslated = '';

ngOnInit() {
  this.keyTranslated = this.translateService.instant('key');
}
```

and then in your html you can write:

```
<form>
  <input [placeholder]=keyTranslated>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for offering a basic explanation alongside your code. That’s something a lot of new contributors neglect to do. Good work!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the above ts file's work is needed. I also tried it but didn't work for me. 
**en.json**

```
{
  "app-name":  "App Name",
  "sign-in": {
     "user-name": "User Name",
     "user-name-placeholder": "Enter user name"
   }
}
```

and in your component's template:

```
    <div class="row form-group mb-3">              
       <label for="userName" class="col-md-4 align-self-center">{{ 'sign-in.user-name' | translate }}</label>        
       <div class="col-md-8"> 
          <div class="input-group">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                 <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                 </span>
              </div>    
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" formControlName="userName" [placeholder]="'sign-in.user-name-placeholder' | translate" />                                        
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved it:

```
<input [placeholder]="'key' | translate">
```

Answer (score 0):

For completely dynamic values in placeholder, value etc. you can use this. **myobj.selectedText** is getting from **.ts file** and **FIELDS.SUBJECT_TEXT** is from **translation(eg. fr.json) file**.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
  [placeholder]="myobj.selectedText + ' ' + ('FIELDS.SUBJECT_TEXT' | translate)"
  [value]="myobj.selectedText + ' ' + ('FIELDS.SUBJECT_TEXT' | translate)" >
```